# Command in a bash script has no effect

Tags: bash, ps

I have put a command in a bash script to kill processes as below

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 $(ps ux | grep 'fluent' | awk '{print $2}')
```

As I run the script, e.g. `./mykill`, it has no effect

```
$ ps ux | grep fluent
ko 21690  0.0  0.0 112664   972 pts/3    S+   15:28   0:00 grep --color=auto fluent
ko 26573  5.1  1.0 1743688 673592 ?      Sl   May14 836:08 /state/partition1/ans190/v190/fluent/cortex.19.0.0 -f fluent -cmd-port:35881:compute-0-4.local -workbench-session (fluent "3ddp -pshmem  -host -alnamd64 -r19.0.0 -t16 -mpi=ibmmpi -path/state/partition1/ansys190/v190/fluent -ssh")
ko 26581  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    May14   0:00 [fluent] <defunct>
$
$
$ ~/mykill
Killed
$ ps ux | grep fluent
ko 21690  0.0  0.0 112664   972 pts/3    S+   15:28   0:00 grep --color=auto fluent
ko 26573  5.1  1.0 1743688 673592 ?      Sl   May14 836:08 /state/partition1/ans190/v190/fluent/cortex.19.0.0 -f fluent -cmd-port:35881:compute-0-4.local -workbench-session (fluent "3ddp -pshmem  -host -alnamd64 -r19.0.0 -t16 -mpi=ibmmpi -path/state/partition1/ansys190/v190/fluent -ssh")
ko 26581  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    May14   0:00 [fluent] <defunct>
```

However, if I run the command in the terminal, it will kill them.

```
$ kill -9 $(ps ux | grep 'fluent' | awk '{print $2}')
-bash: kill: (21899) - No such process
$ ps ux | grep fluent
ko 21915  0.0  0.0 112664   972 pts/3    S+   15:31   0:00 grep --color=auto fluent
```

What is the reason then?

Comment: Related: [When should I not kill -9 a process?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/8916)

Comment: What is the relation between my question and that? I didn't understand.

Comment: You may want to try `pkill` instead.

Comment: `pkill` is also incomplete. Because I have to kill multiple process names. for example, `pkill fluent`, `pkill cortex` and others. That command will kill all things.

Comment: I posted the link to that other question because you are using `kill -9`.  This is usually not a good idea in the general case. It's a related question.

Comment: Then you should try using `pkill -f`.

Comment: I know, but as you can see there are some `defunct` processes and I think `kill -9` is the best at the moment.

Comment: Defunct processes (zombies) don't respond to signals. They will hang around until their parent process reaps them.

Comment: "Generally, send 15, and wait a second or two, and if that doesn't
work, send 2, and if that doesn't work, send 1.  If that doesn't,
REMOVE THE BINARY because the program is badly behaved!"

Comment: Notice too that depending on the ordering of the returned PIDs from `ps`, the `grep` may be killed before other processes, which is why it's always better to use `pkill`.

Comment: The `grep` should be dead and reaped by the time the `kill` runs. The danger is that its PID could be already reused for another innocent process. But yes, `kill $(ps ...)` sucks, doubly so because of the pretentious `grep | awk` mannerism.

Comment: @mahmood surely the difference between `~/mykill` and `./mykill` is just a typo? you're not running a different script than the one you're showing?

Comment: @mosvy: the script is in home. So, `~/` and `./` are the same.

Comment: your problem is not reproducible, sorry. use `pkill` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach.

The way you detect processes is not reliable. A process may have `fluent` in its command line even if it isn't the one you wanted to kill. For example, if you call your script `kill-fluent`, it'll kill itself. **Never kill a process just based on its name**. It's far too unreliable.

The best way to kill a process is to use its own remote control mechanism to send an exit command. If that's not possible, kill it based on what files it has open with [`fuser`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fuser.1.html). Executing a binary counts as having it open. For example, to kill all processes that are executing `/usr/bin/fluent`, run `fuser -k /usr/bin/fluent`.

In cases where you really have to kill a process based on its command line, don't use `grep`. `ps … | grep …` may include the grep process: the `ps` command and the `grep` command run in parallel, so `ps` may or may not list `grep` depending on the relative speed at which the two processes start. Use [`pkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) instead.

As for the `<defunct>` processes, forget about killing them: they're already dead. That's what “defunct” means: they're [zombies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155012/how-does-linux-handles-zombie-process/155016#155016).

Comment: FWIW, always `fuser -TERM -k /path/to/binary` -- if someone really wants to send a `SIGKILL`, they will figure out how to remove the `-TERM` or change it to `-KILL`.